# My react app keep refresh url I can't get the token from spotify

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

after I do this

```
const loginUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
                'client_id=' + token +
                (scopes ? '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes) : '') +
                '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri) +
                '&response_type=token';
            window.location = loginUrl;
```

it pass me to Spotify's login page and after I login it takes me back to redirect_url which currently is localhost with token parameter
but after that in a second, the URL is being wipeout from 'localhost:3000#access_token' to 'localhost:3000'

I want to get the access_token but I can't. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you register your app correctly?

Comment: I only set "http://localhost:3000/" in the Redirect URLs section. Not sure if it correct or not but if I don't put it will give me an error.

Comment: I mean if you set the redirect_uri, scopes correctly on the developer console. the redirect_uri should be full URL - http://localhost:3000